# Replacing elements containing escape characters / in an XML file using python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, python-2.7

**Question**

I have an XML file. I wish to replace an  XML attribute in lowercase with the mixed case equivalent present on a windows system.

What is the best way to do a replacement on the source XML?

My initial impulse was to use Regex. However Regex looks messy because of the escaping needed for the paths.  I then  thought about using sed but there must be a better way.

Is there a python module recommended for this type of operation?

**Background**

This is because I have 2 programs (A,B) creating the XML on a windows system. Program A outputs XML with mixed case filepaths. Program B outputs lowercase filepaths. These filepaths are compared on a Linux system by program C so match fails. I have no access to the output of program A or configuration of program C.

**XML source**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<disk>
<files>
 <file name="C:\mydisk\dir1\myfile\myfile.cpp" >
</files>
</disk>
```

**Python script**

```
from __future__ import print_function 
import sys
from lxml import etree  as ET
from win32file import  GetLongPathName,GetFullPathName
from win32api import FindFiles

# I can use the win32  module to extract the correct path.

def GetFilePathAndNameinTrueCase(filename) :
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        try:
            fullname = GetLongPathName(filename)
            firstmatchingfileobject = FindFiles(filename)
            filenamewithcase   = firstmatchingfileobject[0][8]
            pathwithcase = GetFullPathName(filename)
            patharray  =  pathwithcase.split( '\\' )
            pathonlylist = patharray[:-1]
            pathonly = '\\'.join(pathonlylist)
            nameandfilepathwithcase =  pathonly  +  '\\'  +  filenamewithcase
            return nameandfilepathwithcase

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return False

# I can use the lxml module to extract the filenames and paths from the xml.

def ExtractFilenameFromXML(myxmlfile):
    fileslist = []
    root = ET.parse(myxmlfile)
    # use xpath to find the filenames in the XML
    for filepath in root.findall("disk/files/file"):
        filestr = filepath.attrib['name']
        fileslist.append( filestr)

    #remove duplicates in the list 

    fileslist = list(set(fileslist))
    return fileslist  

def ReplaceLowercaseFilepathwithCorrectCase(filename):
     # Is there a pythonic way to replace XML elements containing \ escape characters?

if __name__=='__main__':
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv)<2:
        print( "Please specify a file name")
    else:
        ReplaceLowercaseFilepathwithCorrectCase(sys.argv[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This does it. It was a simple string replacement in the end. Needs linting now though.

```
'''

'''
from __future__ import print_function 
import sys
from lxml import etree  as ET
import fileinput
from pathlib import Path, PurePath


def PrintFilePathAndNameCase(filepath) :
    mypath = Path(filepath)
    if mypath.exists():
        try:
            patharray  =  filepath.split( '\\' )
            for index, part in enumerate(mypath.parts):
                mypath = mypath.joinpath(part) 
                realname =  mypath.parts[index]
                for child in mypath.parent.iterdir(): 
                    if  child.name.lower() == realname:
                        if  child.name != realname:
                            patharray[index] = child.name
            pathonly = '\\'.join(patharray)
            return   pathonly

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return False
    else:
         return False


def ExtractFilenameFromXML(coverageresultsfilename):
    filesanalysedlist = []
    root = ET.parse(coverageresultsfilename)


    for fileanalysed in root.findall("disk/files/file"):
        fileanalysednameandpath = fileanalysed.attrib['name']
        filesanalysedlist.append( fileanalysednameandpath)

    #remove duplicates in the list 
    filesanalysedlistunique = []
    filesanalysedlistunique = list(set(filesanalysedlist))
    return filesanalysedlistunique



def ReplaceLowercaseFilenamewithMixedCaseFilename(coverageresultsfile):
    '''
    Iterates through the list of filenames in the XML files and for each one
    scans the filesystem for a mixed case equivalent. If the equivalent exists then
    the existing filename is replaced by it. 



    '''

    filesanalysedlist = []
    filesanalysedlist = ExtractFilenameFromXML(coverageresultsfile)

    for item in filesanalysedlist:
        caseitem = PrintFilePathAndNameCase(item) 
        if caseitem is not False:
            with fileinput.input(files=(coverageresultsfile),inplace=True,backup='backup' ) as f:
                for line in f:
                    line = line.replace( item[2:], caseitem[2:] )
                    print(line, end='',flush=True) 
    return True

if __name__=='__main__':
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv)<2:
        print( "Please specify a file name")
    else:
        ReplaceLowercaseFilenamewithMixedCaseFilename(sys.argv[1])
```